# Get custom user attributes from AD in weblogic

Tags: java, security, ldap, weblogic

CAn anybody describe me how to get additional user attributes from AD using weblogic security?
I have configured security provider and trying to authenticate in my JEE application.

```
        HttpServletRequest request =
            (HttpServletRequest)((ServletRequest)ADFContext.getCurrent().getEnvironment().getRequest());
        CallbackHandler handler =
            new SimpleCallbackHandler(username, password);               
        try {
            Subject subject = Authentication.login(handler);
            ServletAuthentication.runAs(subject, request);              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }
```

Everything is OK. But from Subject I can take only user login and role, but I need user phone and employeeNumber. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have retrieved the user name from the `Subject` you're going to have to issue an LDAP query to get the extra information. It will look something like the following:

```
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://yourldap:389");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapqueryuser + "@yourldap");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapqueryuserpassword);

// initializing active directory LDAP connection
dirContext = new InitialDirContext(properties);
dirContext.search(name, filter, cons)
```

These examples are pretty thorough:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/examples/directory.html
http://myjeeva.com/querying-active-directory-using-java.html

The java doc for InitialDirContext is here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.html